# Blank Screen not working anymore

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, lock-screen

I was using Focal Fossa and the screen energy saving timeout worked perfectly, until it didn't!

Out of the blue, it just stopped working.
I checked if it was actually enabled, if the timeout was set (5 minutes), etc...
 everything looked OK, but still, after 6h, not a single time did it went blank!
Worse, it's supposed to lock the session (but not hibernate), and this also doesn't work anymore!
I really don't get what's happening, there's no new app that could prevent it.
I just upgraded to Jammy Jellyfish, thinking it might solve the issue, rebooted... Nope.
The only other post with a similar problem seemed to have been "magically" solved by a reboot. 
Great for the OP, but not very helpful since no cause could be identified :/

If this can be of any use, `"$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = wayland`

Any help or clue is welcome...